# Authorization Token of Pages

Tags: flutter, dart, token, where-clause, invalidation

I have this error;
Could there be a problem with the token.It says Uri invalid token, but I login beforehand, why can't I read it? Headers I add token like this..But it isnt work how solve it ? What could I have done wrong?

And So map, ifwhere, where or other things dont work..
I'm new to this platform, I may have asked something very simple, sorry for that.
Thank you for all ....

```
    import 'dart:async';
    import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
    import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_knowin_app/core/data/response.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_knowin_app/core/util/constants.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_knowin_app/features/promotions/domain/entities/check.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_knowin_app/features/promotions/domain/entities/spin.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_knowin_app/features/promotions/domain/repositories/spin_repository.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_knowin_app/features/promotions/domain/usecases/check_regular.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_knowin_app/features/promotions/domain/usecases/check_vip.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_knowin_app/injection_container.dart';
    
    part 'spin_event.dart';
    part 'spin_state.dart';
    
    
    
    enum SpinPageState {
      regular,
      vip,
    }
    class SpinBloc extends Bloc<SpinEvent, SpinState> {
      final SpinRepository spinRepository = sl<SpinRepository>();
      SpinPageState spinPageState;
      bool stateVip;
      bool spinState = false;
      String winThing;
      int winResult;
      int gamePlayCountVip;
      int gamePlayCountRegular;
      checksRegular ChecksRegular;
      checksVip ChecksVip;
    
    
    
      SpinBloc({
        @required checksRegular ChecksRegular,
        @required checksVip ChecksVip,
    
    
      })
          : assert(checksRegular != null),
            assert(checksVip != null),
    
    
            ChecksRegular = ChecksRegular,
            ChecksVip = ChecksVip,
    
    
    
            super(SpinState.initial());
    
    
      @override
      Stream<SpinState> mapEventToState(SpinEvent event,) async* {
        final SpinRepository spinRepository = sl<SpinRepository>();
        SpinState.initial();
    
          if (event is SpinLoadingEvent) {
            Response updateResponse;
            yield SpinLoadingState();
    
            final checkRegularOrFailure = await ChecksRegular(
                checksRegularParams());
            final checkVipOrFailure = await ChecksVip(
                checksVipParams());
    
            checkRegularOrFailure.fold((failure) {
              updateResponse = Response(
                status: false,
    
                message: UNEXPECTED_FAILURE_MESSAGE,
                statusCode: "FAIL CHECK REGULAR",
              );
            }, (response) {
              spinState = true;
              spinPageState = SpinPageState.regular;
    
             response.toList().where((e){
              print("PEOPLE COUNT= ${ e.gamePlayed}");
             });
    
            });
            checkVipOrFailure.fold((failure) {
              updateResponse = Response(
                status: false,
                message: UNEXPECTED_FAILURE_MESSAGE,
                statusCode: "FAIL CHECK VIP",
              );
            }, (response) {
    
              spinState = true;
              spinPageState = SpinPageState.vip;
            });
            yield SpinLoadingState();
          }
          if (event is SpinStartEvent) {
    
          }
    
      }
    }


RemoteCode;

    class PromotionRemoteDataSourceImpl implements PromotionRemoteDataSource {
      String token;
      final http.Client client;
    
      PromotionRemoteDataSourceImpl({this.client});
      Map<String, String> get defaultHeaders =>
          {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          };
    
    
      Map<String, String> get defaultQueryParams => {
        "lang": Platform.localeName.split('_')[0],
      };
    
      @override
      Future<List<Check>> checksRegular() async {
        Uri uri = Uri.https(
            API_URL,
            '/promotions/check/regular',
          defaultQueryParams,
        );
        print("URİ: "+ uri.toString());
        final response = await client.get(uri, headers: defaultHeaders);
        final  body= json.decode(response.body);
```

Comment: Check your API credentials.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the error like this;

```
void initState() {
        super.initState();
    
         WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
               
                sl<PromotionRemoteDataSource>().token = userState.token;//!!!
                
            });
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here

```
response.toList().where((e){
              print("PEOPLE COUNT= ${ e.gamePlayed}");
             });
```

The reason why is as the error message stated. The response variable is null, and you're trying to convert null to a list and Dart didn't like that. Implement some way to deal with the scenario where response is null, e.g. have an if statement there, and that should hopefully solve your problem

Comment: thank you, I tried this but couldn't run it